# Returning a priority_queue with custom comparator

Tags: c++, priority-queue, standard-library

I have a function that needs to return a sorted list based on some input parameters. I've selected a `std::priority_queue` to hold this list.

But the compiler is giving me an error I don't recognize. Here's the code I have:

```
struct DepthCompare {
    bool operator()
        (const struct inst *&lhs, const struct inst *&rhs) const
    {
        return lhs->depth < rhs->depth;
    }
};

typedef priority_queue<struct inst*> HeuristicList;
HeuristicList getHeuristicList(struct BasicBlock &) {

    HeuristicList ret( DepthCompare );
    return ret;
}
```

The compiler says that a `conversion from 'HeuristicList (*)(DepthCompare)' to non-scalar type 'HeuristicList' requested`  on the return statement's line.

It doesn't look like I'm trying to return a pointer. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems.

To use a custom comparator, you must specify the comparator type as the third template argument:

```
typedef priority_queue<inst*, vector<inst*>, DepthCompare> HeuristicList;
```

`HeuristicList ret( DepthCompare );` is interpreted as a function declaration, rather than a variable declaration, giving the error that you're seeing. You need to pass an instance of the comparator, and make sure it can't be interpreted as a function declaration:

```
HeuristicList ret = HeuristicList(DepthCompare());
```

However, since the constuctor's first argument is optional, and defaults to a default-constructed comparator, you can simply write

```
HeuristicList ret;
```

Or, since you're just returning the variable straight away,

```
return HeuristicList();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a lot more reading to do to understand all this. Coming from Java, I've passed around anonymous objects a few times, and thought C++ would be the same way. And of course, I left out the body of `getHeuristicList()` for clarity, so I won't be returning it immediately.

I need a manual on interpreting gcc error messages too!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the comparator is the third template parameter of `priority_queue`.  You must declare your `priority_queue` like such:

```
typedef priority_queue<inst*, vector<inst*>, DepthCompare> HeuristicList;
```

This assumes you want to use `vector` as the backing container (default).

Also note that in your comparator functor, you want to declare the parameters as const reference to a pointer.  What you have is a reference to a pointer to const.  You want this:

```
bool operator()(inst* const& lhs, inst* const& rhs) const
```

You also don't need to pass an instance of your comparator object to the `priority_queue` constructor, as the default comparator constructor will do just fine.